# Two Elements, One Scrollbar, Neither Scroll Out Of Plane

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q6q499ew/

So far, I have a very basic system to start with, so if you scroll past a certain point it should become stuck until you start scrolling back up.

```
$(".body").scroll(function(){ 
    $(".mainContent").toggleClass("stickyBottom", $(this).scrollTop()>1040)
}).scroll()
```

I would like to be able to have it so that, regardless whether the `sidebar` or `main content` is greater in height, the one which is least tall will stop when it is at the bottom of the div, scrolling back up will scroll both until one reaches the top but the other can still scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but ultimately what you want to do is use an `if` statement to `addClass("stickyBottom")` when the scroll is beyond 1040 and `removeClass("stickyBottom")` when the scroll is less than 1040.

```
$(".body").scroll(function() { 
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1040) {
    $(".mainContent").addClass("stickyBottom");
  } else {
    $(".mainContent").removeClass("stickyBottom");
  }
});
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/q6q499ew/3/).

Comment: Your fiddle seems to have a problem I am having in which the fixed element is taken out from the parents container and you cannot use mouse wheel over this element to scroll the sections. In addition, I'm looking to be able to scroll both within via one scroll, they simply stick when they reach the top and/or bottom.

Comment: I think you noticed this yourself whilst I was making a comment!

Comment: As the sidebar and main content elements are 10% and 90% in my example, this is including the scrollbar, however with adding the sticky class, it seems to jump outside this container and is 90% of the entire area so masks the scroller and cannot scroll via the parent. Not really sure where to go with this!

Comment: @TimMarshall You can add a `z-index` so that `mainContent` overflow doesn't conceal the scroll bar. I've updated my jsFiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q6q499ew/3/

Comment: Yes, however that modifies the content there within, thus I'm really looking for another solution to achieve this effect

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what you mean by "modifies the content". The text content is unchanged, the dimensions remain the same as your original fiddle, but the desired scroll effect is now present. You might need to clarify what it is that you're looking for.

Comment: Adding `p {text-align:justify;}` will help you to see it.Alike I explained earlier, it is 90% width of the parent element which includes the scrollbar, upon fixing, this becomes 90% of the entire width, no scrollbar accounted for, so when you apply the `z-indexing`, the text is cut off by about 2 chars.